# Is there a way in mustache to render a block if a section is present without iterating?

Tags: html, mustache, mustache.php

I have a section with a header that I want to show only if the array is populated, something like this:

```
<h1> These are the elements in the array </h1>
<ul>
    {{#myArray}}
    <li>{{name}} - {{value}}</li>
    {{/myArray}}
</ul>
```

How can I render the `<h1>` only if `myArray` is populated?

If i put it inside the # section it is rendered once for every element in the array, which is not what i want.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: That is the correct way

Comment: The "correct" way is to prepare your view before rendering, or to pass an object with a method :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{#myArray.length}}
     <h1> These are the elements in the array </h1>
{{/myArray.length}}
```

The .length will return 0 for empty arrays so we have achieved a real falsey value.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/recag/1/edit)**

**In terms of PHP:**

```
{{#myArray.0}}
     <h1> These are the elements in the array </h1>
{{/myArray.0}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, probably because I'm using mustache through php which means that arrays don't have the `.length` method.

Comment: updated the answer. Before there was an extra # at the closing tag

Comment: Could you please try this : {{#myArray.0}}, i have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, with `{{#myArray.0}}` it works, thanks. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: The name.0 notation also works in Python with [chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron). You can extend this to render a list conditional on it containing at least _n_ items.