# In Mustache, is there a way to check of the list has items, but not repeat it?

Tags: mustache.php

I would like to be able to check if a list is empty, and if it's not print a block, but I don't want to repeat that block for each item. I just want to be able to echo it once.

Give this following structure:

```
array(
    "teasers" => array(
        array("title"=>"Teaser Title 1"),
        array("title"=>"Teaser Title 2")
    )
);


{{# teasers }}

    <div class="items-wrap">

        <div class="items">

            {{# . }}

                <div class="item">

                    {{ title }}

                </div>

            {{/ . }}

           </div>

    </div>

{{/ teasers }}
```

I would like the **items-wrap** div to only print once, and repeat the **item** div for each item in the array. As is right now, the items-wrap is repeating once for each item in the teasers array. So... is there a way to check if the main array is not empty, but not repeat it?

The goal is to only print the **items-wrap** once, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a way. Mustache has the method `length`. If equal ZERO, is false and the block will not be rendered. Your example:

```
{{# teasers.length }}
<div class="items-wrap">
    <div class="items">
        {{# teasers }}
            <div class="item">
                {{ title }}
            </div>
        {{/ teasers }}
    </div>
</div>
{{/ teasers.length }}
```

The tag `{{teasers.length}}` will check the number of items inside `{{teasers}}` and will render the block only if not empty.

More information [here](https://www.vodori.com/helpful-mustache-template-tips/).

This answer is too late, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

> In terms of PHP:
>
> {{#myArray.0}}...{{/myArray.0}}

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786928/5546916

Comment: This works in Python (with [chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron)) also.

Answer (score 0):

user "_has_items" , example: myarray_has_items willcheck the contion whether arry is empty or not then the tag wont render

or you can use {{#items.length}} to check length before render

```
{{#items.length}}
<ul>
    {{items}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/items}}`enter code here`
</ul>
```

{{/items.length}}